# Folder structure wrong when creating a nuget package from csproj

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I'm creating a nuget package from a class library project I made with Visual Studio 2013. My project has the following file structure:

[image]

I generated the nuspec file and left it pretty much unchanged. If I understood the [NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package) correctly, 'nuget pack Infrastructure.csproj' should result in a package with the following structure:

[image]

Only it doesn't. I get this:

[image]

If I install this package, test.js doesn't end up in '~/Scripts/Infrastructure/test.js' but in '~/Content/Scripts/Infrastructure/test.js'. What could I be doing wrong? And is there a way to configure this behaviour in the nuspec file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is eliminate your *Content* folder, in other words put the *Scripts* folder in the **root** of the source project.

Doing this will cause the *Scripts* folder to be installed into the root of the project in which you're installing the Nuget package.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I just assumed the conventions for packaging a working directory applied to packaging a project as well, but I see now that they don't. I do wonder now how to include a .cs file from my project into the package, but that's another question. Thanks again!

Comment: Anything you put in the root of your project (as long as build type is set to "content") will be automatically copied into the project that the package is being installed into, including folders. I'm glad i was able to be of help.